# How do I present a UIAlertController in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

In UIKit, it is common to present `UIAlertController` for modal pop up alert messages in response to some action.

Is there a modal alert controller type in SwiftUI?

Is there a way to present a `UIAlertController` from SwiftUI classes? It seems like this may be possible using `UIViewControllerRepresentable` but not sure if that is required?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`Alert`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/alert) instead.

```
import SwiftUI

struct SwiftUIView: View {
    @State private var showAlert = false;
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: { self.showAlert = true }) {
            Text("Show alert")
        }.alert(
            isPresented: $showAlert,
            content: { Alert(title: Text("Hello world")) }
        )
    }
}
```

Bind to `isPresented` in order to control the presentation.

**UPDATE:**

As James Toomey mentioned in the comments, there is a better way:
`alert(_:isPresented:presenting:actions:message:)`

Official doc: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/alert(_:ispresented:presenting:actions:message:)-8584l

Comment: Thanks.  Indeed using Alert (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/alert) in SwiftUI appears appropriate.  Is binding for the presentation expected paradigm?

Comment: Generally speaking yes, thanks to "Single source of truth" thingy. You can use MVVM and trigger the `showAlert` flag from the `ViewModel` for example.

Comment: Deprecated, use this now: [https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/alert(_:ispresented:presenting:actions:message:)-8584l](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/alert(_:ispresented:presenting:actions:message:)-8584l)

Answer (score 13):

This just works:

```
class func alertMessage(title: String, message: String) {
    let alertVC = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) { (action: UIAlertAction) in
    }
    alertVC.addAction(okAction)
    
    let viewController = UIApplication.shared.windows.first!.rootViewController!
    viewController.present(alertVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Put it in a Helper-Class.

Usage:

```
Helper.alertMessage(title: "Test-Title", message: "It works - even in SwiftUI")
```

Comment: I called Helper.alertMessage(...) from the action of my button... Thx it works as expected

Comment: Remove the class declaration and the closure on the action, still works.. It worked for me using last instead of first.

Comment: As of iOS 15 `rootViewController` is deprecated. If you're using SwiftUI it's better to update to its `.alert(isPresented:, content:)` method

Comment: this won't work if there is a sheet presenting on the screen.

Comment: Please don't do this. This is a massive hack and very fragile. Use the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using extension of UIViewController to get current vc and UIAlertController to present 'Alert'. Maybe you can try this as followings:

extension for UIViewController

```
extension UIViewController {
class func getCurrentVC() -> UIViewController? {
var result: UIViewController?
var window = UIApplication.shared.windows.first { $0.isKeyWindow }
        if window?.windowLevel != UIWindow.Level.normal {
            let windows = UIApplication.shared.windows
            for tmpWin in windows {
                if tmpWin.windowLevel == UIWindow.Level.normal {
                    window = tmpWin
                    break
                }
            }
        }
        let fromView = window?.subviews[0]
        if let nextRespnder = fromView?.next {
            if nextRespnder.isKind(of: UIViewController.self) {
                result = nextRespnder as? UIViewController
                result?.navigationController?.pushViewController(result!, animated: false)
            } else {
                result = window?.rootViewController
            }
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

extension for UIAlertController

```
extension UIAlertController {
    //Setting our Alert ViewController, presenting it.
    func presentAlert() {
        ViewController.getCurrentVC()?.present(self, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func dismissAlert() {
        ViewController.getCurrentVC()?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

And you can create your showAlert function now

```
func showMyAlert() {
let myAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Confirm order", message: "Are you sure to order two box of chocolate?", preferredStyle: .alert)
let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok!", style: .default) { (_) in
print("You just confirm your order")
} 
let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) { (_) in
print(You cancel it already!)
}
myAlert.addAction(okAction)
myAlert.addAction(cancelAction)
myAlert.presentAlert()
}
```

Wish my answer can help you. :-)

Comment: It works on my project. But I don't know whether it works on your project or not.

Answer (score -2):

You can present UIKit Alert in SwiftUI using notificationCenter

At SceneDelegate.swift on  "func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions)" insert this code {

```
   NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.showAlert), name: Notification.Name("showAlert"), object: nil)
```

and add this function

```
  @objc private func showAlert(notification: NSNotification){
        let msg: String = notification.object as! String
        let alert =  UIAlertController(title: "Title", message: msg, preferredStyle: .alert)
        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "οκ", style: .cancel) { (action) in
        }
        alert.addAction(cancelAction)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.window?.rootViewController?.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
```

Now you can make the app to appear a message with  UIKit AlertController writing this code on an action in a swifui class

```
 var body: some View {
        Button(action:{
               NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("showAlert"), object: "Ελέγξτε το δίκτυο σας και προσπαθήστε αργότερα.")
 }
}
```