# SwiftUI - Cannot show alert over sheet

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

The story is a little long. First, let me show some code that doesn't work as I expected.

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var isPresentingAlert = false
    @State var isPresentingSheet = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Show Sheet") {
                isPresentingSheet = true
            }
        }
        .alert("Alert", isPresented: $isPresentingAlert) {}
        .sheet(isPresented: $isPresentingSheet) {
            Button("Show Alert") {
                isPresentingAlert = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The code's intent is clear: the view should display a sheet when user press the "Show Sheet" button, and there is a "Show Alert" button on the sheet, which should cause the alert window to show after tapping. The code is simplified - in the original app, the sheet shows a form to the user, and the alert should show when user submit a form with some invalid data.

But actually when I pressed the "Show Alert" button, the alert wasn't shown. Instead, I got following error in the console:

```
2023-02-14 23:41:08.163349+0800 SheetAndAlert[8351:217492] [Presentation] Attempt to
present <SwiftUI.PlatformAlertController: 0x15b030600> on
<_TtGC7SwiftUI19UIHostingControllerGVS_15ModifiedContentVS_7AnyViewVS_12RootModifier__:
0x15b00aa00> (from
<_TtGC7SwiftUI19UIHostingControllerGVS_15ModifiedContentVS_7AnyViewVS_12RootModifier__:
0x15b00aa00>) which is already presenting
<_TtGC7SwiftUI29PresentationHostingControllerVS_7AnyView_: 0x15b02e000>.
```

I had no idea what does this error means. Later I changed the code to use UIKIt's `UIAlertController`, wishing I can get around the error. (The code was adapted from this answer: [How do I present a UIAlertController in SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58548569/how-do-i-present-a-uialertcontroller-in-swiftui))

```swift
import SwiftUI 

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var isPresentingAlert = false
    @State var isPresentingSheet = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Show Sheet") {
                isPresentingSheet = true
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $isPresentingSheet) {
            Button("Show Alert") {
                ContentView.alertMessage(title: "Alert", message: "Alert")
            }
        }
    }
    
    static func alertMessage(title: String, message: String) {
        let alertVC = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) { (action: UIAlertAction) in
        }
        alertVC.addAction(okAction)
        
        let viewController = UIApplication.shared.windows.first!.rootViewController!
        viewController.present(alertVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

But still, it doesn't work. A similiar error is thrown:

```
2023-02-14 23:56:12.715039+0800 SheetAndAlert[9991:263667] [Presentation] Attempt to
present <UIAlertController: 0x13d80b800> on
<_TtGC7SwiftUI19UIHostingControllerGVS_15ModifiedContentVS_7AnyViewVS_12RootModifier__:
0x139012600> (from
<_TtGC7SwiftUI19UIHostingControllerGVS_15ModifiedContentVS_7AnyViewVS_12RootModifier__:
0x139012600>) which is already presenting
<_TtGC7SwiftUI29PresentationHostingControllerVS_7AnyView_: 0x13b02fc00>.
```

Finally I found a working solution, just move `.alert` inside `.sheet`'s content:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var isPresentingAlert = false
    @State var isPresentingSheet = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Show Sheet") {
                isPresentingSheet = true
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $isPresentingSheet) {
            Button("Show Alert") {
                isPresentingAlert = true
            }
            .alert("Alert", isPresented: $isPresentingAlert) {}
        }
    }
}
```

Though works, but I still don't understand (at all!) why using `UIAlertController` cannot solve the problem, while just moving the modifier to another place can.

Comment: That root view controller is what SwiftUI uses to present its own views, the controller is already busy presenting. Don’t use that root view controller access “trick” it is terrible practice. So many things get blocked if you do.

Answer (score 8):

**TL;DR:** This behavior is a constraint of the UIKit layer used by SwiftUI and the solution is what you already found, to present the alert from the body of the `.sheet` modifier.

---

The behavior you're seeing is caused by the underlying UIKit layer that SwiftUI relies on.

In UIKit, content is managed by `UIViewControllers`, each one of these view controllers can present another view controller on top of it, **but only one**. This is often used to present "modals" (or sheets), "popovers" and "alerts".

View controllers are invisible to us when using SwiftUI, but they are still there. Some SwiftUI structs map to some UIKit view controllers, like `NavigationView` to `UINavigationController`, and `TabView` to `UITabViewController`.

As you may have guessed by now, the `.sheet` and the `.alert` modifiers map to their own view controllers. `.sheet` specifically creates a new view controller that is presented on top of the current view controller.

As I mentioned earlier, view controllers in UIKit can present only one view controller at any time. Because both modifiers are modifying the same content, and hence the same view controller, trying to activate both at the same time will give you that error.

The fix is what you already found: moving the `.alert` modifier *inside* the body of `.sheet` will cause the alert to be presented on the sheet view controller.

Comment: Thanks for such useful answer, but I still wondering the corresponding relationship between SwiftUI View and UIKit's UIViewController. Does every View has a paired UIKitController under the hooks, or there are just a small amount of UIViewController, each managing multiple SwiftUI View throughout entire app's life?

Answer (score 0):

If you really need that, I think there is only a bit of hacky solution for that:

```
.sheet(isPresented: $isPresentingSheet) {
    Button("Show Alert") {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
             isPresentingAlert = true
        }
    }
}
```

The other solution that comes to my mind is that you can watch `.onChange` for `isPresentingSheet` and call the alert from there (I haven't tested this one it might end up to need `asyncAfter` too). Obviously you need to add some more variables to know what has happened in your `sheet` as every dismiss shouldn't call the alert. It is less hacky but more complex to implement and less readable overall.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing is using 1 Sheet View, on click of a tooltip icon I replace the X (close) button of the Sheet with a back button and I replace the contents of the Sheet with the tooltip text.

So in the end I kept using 1 view but make it appear like 2. Not the most gorgeous solution but then again it's not a great UX but it's exactly what the people paying me requested.